# Unable to delete ACM certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-certificate-manager, aws-acm, aws-acm-certificate

I was running a basic website using CloudFront, Route53 and ACM on AWS. The whole infrastructure was created a few months ago using Terraform and experienced no issues with it so far.

At the moment, I have no more use for this site so I decided to bring all the resources up by deleting them. While everything went through smoothly, Terraform was unable to delete the ACM certificate associated with the CloudFront distributions, even though it managed to delete them correctly.

At the moment ACM shows the certificate as being attached to a CloudFront distribution which does not exist and attempting to delete manually results in the typical `Certificate in use` message. I tried leaving the resources deleted and re-trying on a later time, hoping that any lingering changes would have propagated but attempting to delete this even on a later time still fails.

I have also tried querying CloudFront distributions using the CLI by doing a `aws cloudfront list-distributions` and I see no resources in place.

Anyone knows on how to resolve this?

Comment: Related [support KB article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/acm-certificate-resources/).

Comment: Yeap, I have came across this but I am unable to understand how to proceed. The article states several steps, none of which seem to match my case. For example, I have no API Gateway in place or Cognito or ElasticSearch. The only current association I see is with that deleted CloudFront distribution. What should I be deleting in this case?